# Unable to override admin templates in Django 3.0

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Here is my settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And here is my template base_site.html in templates/admin/accounts/ (accounts is my app name):

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}School name{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Django administration') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

But this template is not overriding existing templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to override the template `templates/admin/base_site.html` you have to have the same folder structure in your app.

You have `myapp/templates/admin/accounts/base_site.html`, but what you need is **myapp/templates/admin/base_site.html**. Then it should work.

The order of `INSTALLED_APPS` might be also important then.

-> [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-an-app-s-template-directory)

Comment: base_site.html extends `admin/base.html`, does it also needs to be copied over along with base_site.html? Thanks!

Comment: @xjlin0 only if base.html has content you want to change which are not available to be overwritten from within base_site.html. You don't need to copy that template if you don't need to change anything within it.